How can I fix React Native app crashing only on real device when upgraded to targetSdk 34?
So i've been working on an app for about a year now, two apps actually, an e-hailing app, a rider and a driver app.
now i'm done and about to post to google play store, google play store won't allow target SDKs less than 34.
My app is built on sdk 33, so i have to change it sdk 34, the problem now is, the app runs on android emulator fine, but not on real device, it crashes instantly with several errors but three major ones
App built with: react-native version : 0.71.12
ERRORS
07-07 08:12:30.518 11330 11330 E SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
07-07 08:12:30.614 11330 11330 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 08:12:30.614 11330 11330 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.roundtripzdriver, PID: 11330
07-07 08:12:30.614 11330 11330 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.roundtripzdriver.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created
and
07-07 08:12:30.614 11330 11330 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.roundtripzdriver: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
when i revert to sdk33 it works fine on emulator and on real device
buildscript {
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34

// We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
}
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8")
}
}

the funny thing is this is the exact config i have on the rider app, with the only difference being
the rider app has a lower react-native version of 0.71.4 and in the buildscript.dependencies has a classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
while the driver app (the one crashing) has a higher react native version of 0.71.12 and in the buildscript.dependencies has a classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
I tried changing the classpath of the driver app to fit the rider app, but no change
honestly, I've been on this for a week now, and can't find any solution, I'm at my wits end, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have been facing the same issue solution which worked for me
open MainApplication.java file and add this code
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Build;
    import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
    @Override
    public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
            return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
        } else {
            return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        }
    }

make sure to add this code above the oncreate() method.
add this line inside android/app/build.gradle dependencies.
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'

try now

This solution works.

Happy to hear

This solutions works 100%, thanks

Addition to @user3118363's answer you should also upgrade minSdkVersion to 24, and change the Gradle version to 7.4.2 using AGP (Although it hasn't been tested with SDK 34). Then Rerun the Gradle:
Windows:
gradlew cleanBuildCache

Mac and Linux:
./gradlew cleanBuildCache


When you say using AGP, you mean using Android Studio instead of using gradle, right?

Yes. In Android studio tools -> AGP upgrade assistant.

ok, great, i'll give that a try. no wonder, play console still says i'm violating one of their rules even after changing targetSDK to 34. thank you lots

Detailed Docs: https://medium.com/@anaz_19473/react-native-app-crashes-on-upgrading-to-targetsdkversion-34-android-14-f8f575da6b45
follow the below steps to resolve the issue
in your MainApplication.java
import android.content.Context; // make sure you are not 
importing multiple times
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver 
receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && 
       getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, 
        Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
    } else {
        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}

and Ensure that you insert this(@Override…) code before the onCreate() method.
insert this line inside android/app/build.gradle dependencies.
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'

re-run the project.
For some people, this works.
For others, if the issue persists after implementing the above steps, check if you are using react-native-orientation.
If yes, follow the link below.
https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation/issues/429

The answers above would work if your files are in Java but recent React native versions have files in Kotlin instead so here's how I solved it.
Add these imports in your MainApplication.kt file in app/src/main/java
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

Add this above the fun onCreate() function:
override fun registerReceiver(receiver: BroadcastReceiver?, filter: IntentFilter): Intent? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
        super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
    } else {
        super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
    }
}

insert this line inside android/app/build.gradle dependencies.
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'

Rebuild the project, most preferable clearing all cache before doing so.

This has been solved, i just upgraded my react-native version to 0.71.13 from 0.71.12
and also increased the build tools version to 34.0.0
